# fancybox working but not recognizing css, even though everything is linked correctly

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox-2

I'm building an image gallery using fancybox for a college website here: http://pacificdesignacademy.com/NEW/2/gallerygd.php

When an image is clicked, fancybox initializes, but it appears that it doesn't recognize the css or something. There's no border or navigation or anything and sometimes the image will open at the correct size and then jump to the top of the screen and get much smaller. The thumbnails do not seem like they have any css attached to them either. I've checked that everything is linked correctly in the head of my document and I return no errors in the browser. I'm at a loss here.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   true
    }); 

    });
    </script>
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
        <div id="gallery">

            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/gallery/gd/image1.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/gd/thumbs/image1.jpg" alt="Kathleen Watson - Canadian Female Offenders Infographic" /></a>

            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/gallery/gd/image2.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/gd/thumbs/image2.jpg" alt="" /></a>

            <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="img/gallery/gd/image3.jpg"><img src="img/gallery/gd/thumbs/image3.jpg" alt="" /></a>

</div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I watch the network traffic in my browser I see this (200 = success, 404 = not found):

[image: list]

The path to most of your css and javascript files is wrong. Look at the requests that fail, all of them have /NEW/2/NEW/2 in them so that's the problem.

Your current links:

```
<script src="NEW/2/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Why does the browser make these wrong requests? Because you are using relative URL's. Since the current html page is located in `/NEW/2/` the browser will append the url of the requested file to the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the rel attribute instead. This way you even have navigation to browse through the pictures.

HTML

```
<a rel="example_group" title="Custom title" href="/linktopicture">
    <img alt="" src="/linktopicture">
</a>
...
```

CSS:

```
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox( {
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   true   
});
```

See working jsfiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/wm8QD/14/

Comment: I even copied and pasted the exact code from the jsfiddle into my page and the images do the exact same thing.

Comment: And you are 100% sure all scripts are loaded? Maybe use direct (internet) links? http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css (see other in jsfiddle ->External resources). Just to be sure:)

Comment: Firefox tells me that on the link you provided, the fancybox css file is empty (or not found). Using firefox's own inspector I added the css in that file and it worked properly.